# hola tengo un programa en c# que me pide imprimir una fila dada por el usuario en una matriz y he estado intentando pero no lo consigo

Tags: c#

el ejercicio lo estoy haciendo con métodos y no soy muy experto pero me gustaría un poco de ayuda
este es mi código.
Imprimir una fila dada por el usuario.
en si esto es lo que me pide el ejercicio.
y si pueden ver lo trato de hacer con ciclos en el método linea y trate de imprimir la linea de la matriz haciendo pasar los valores de n con un ref pero creo que eso asi no da resultado.
y luego mando a llamar al método al main.

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace arreglo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Pedir(string m, ref int x)
        {
            Console.Write(m);
            x = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());

        }

        static void Llenar(int[,] ma, int n, int m)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write("De el Dato: ");
                    ma[i, j] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                }
        }

        static void Fila(int[,] ma, int n, int m)
        {
           int f = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(ma[0, m] + "  ");
                }
            Console.WriteLine("Esta es la fila: " + f);
        }

        static void Imp(int[,] a, int n, int m)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("El Dato es: " + a[i, j]);
                }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int n = 0;
            Pedir("De el tamaño de la fila: ", ref n);
            int m = 0;
            Pedir("De el tamaño de la columna: ", ref m);
            int[,] ma = new int[n, m];
            Llenar(ma, n, m);
            Console.WriteLine("\n");
            Console.WriteLine("<<< Imprimiendo Matriz >>>");
            Imp(ma, n, m);
            Pedir("que fila quiere imprimir: ", ref n);
            Fila(ma, n, m);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

agradeceria la ayuda. Se que no es muy complejo pero no puedo conseguir que funcione mi metodo.

Comment: al final q quieres hacer, dado un numero de fila, imprimir esa fila completa de la matriz?

Comment: si eso es lo que intento hacer que me imprima toda la fila

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si vos queres imprimir una fila de una matriz, y sabes que fila de la matriz queres imprimir, entonces solo necesitas un metodo que reciba la fila, e itere solo las columnas.

```
static void Fila(int[,] matriz, int fila, int cantidadDeColumnas)
{
    //Ya sabemos que fila es, solo iteramos las columnas
    for (int columna = 0; columna < cantidadDeColumnas; i++)
    {
        //Imprimos la columna que estamos iterando
        Console.Write(matriz[fila, i] + "  ");
    }
    //Con esto, hacemos un enter a los valores que mostramos antes
    Console.WriteLine("");
    Console.WriteLine("Esta es la fila: " + fila);
}
```

Fijate como cambiando algunos nombres de variables, todo se entiende mejor.

### Notas

- Si Pedir va a devolver un valor, no hagas que reciba una variable por referencia, mejor que devuelva un valor.

  ```
  static int Pedir(string m)
  {
      Console.Write(m);
      return Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
  }
  ```

Comment: ok te agradezco las aclaraciones y también tomo en cuenta el ref del método pedir